# SQL Server Managment Studio installation failure

Tags: installation, sql-server

I'm trying to install SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Please, take a look at my screenshots and give me some tips on what's wrong.

[image]

Comment: Try to install manually .NET Framework 4 first.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out this may be helpful...
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-0x80080005-2013-19-t-065144a/f88b7a31-7698-4192-8035-212797cc89ae?auth=1

Or else try installing the .Net framework 4.0,

From next time try attaching the log files too...
Hope this might be useful for you... :-)